# How do I setup ASP.NET MVC to process uploaded data independent of a request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, threadpool

I'm just starting to learn ASP.NET MVC. The website I'm working on requires the user to upload XML files which are loaded into a SQL database through NHibernate. This is working ok now with a small XML file, but once I tried a larger file I started having problems.

When I upload a larger file it takes a while for the data to be written to the database, so on the user's end they get stuck "waiting for local host .. " until the database write is complete and the `Upload()` action method returns a view.

Instead I'd like to set something up like most of the popular movie upload sites, where once the user uploads the file they are immediately sent to another page with a message that says something like "Your upload is being processed please come back later".

I've done a little with multi-threading, but I hardly feel like I know what I am doing. Although, just now I seemed to have gotten my siteworking the way I want using `System.Threading.ThreadPool`.

Is using the thread pool like this the best way to approach this problem?

Here's my Upload() action method.

```
public ActionResult Upload(int id)
{
    //check the type of request
    if (Request.RequestType == "GET")
        {
            //get GET show the upload form
            return View();
        }
        else if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
        {
            //if POST process uploaded file data
            if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
            {
                //copy the upload stream into a memory stream
                System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(memStream);

                //send the the memorystream, id, and username to a new Thread pool work item
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(WriteUploadToDb), new WriteUploadToDbData(id, memStream,User.Identity.Name));

                //send the user to a page
                ViewBag.Message = "Your file is being processed. Please come back later...";
                return RedirectToAction("Reports", new { ID = id });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Multiple report files uploaded!");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my WriteUploadToDb() method which is run on the ThreadPool.

```
private static void WriteUploadToDb(object obj)
    {
        WriteUploadToDbData updateData = (WriteUploadToDbData)obj;

        //resets the stream position
        updateData.Data.Position = 0;

        //creates a new Nhibernate session
        using (var session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var proj = session.Get<Project>(updateData.ProjectID);

                //adds the xml data into the Project
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(updateData.Data);
                proj.AddReport(xmlDoc, updateData.UserName);

                //saves the project to the db
                session.Update(proj);
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }

        //disposes the memory stream
        updateData.Data.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the volume you're doing this at.

For low to modest volume, kicking off an async thread to complete the work is fine.  However, a given web server can only process so many threads (the thread pool has a finite, though configurable, size).

For high volume applications I prefer to have the web server only handle web requests and offload any async processing to another server.  This can be accomplished e.g. using MSMQ or by writing to a log file that another server picks up and processes (the later is commonly used in very high volume applications since writing to a file is a very fast and very reliable process).

The reason I prefer to go this route is that I can scale to handle incoming web service / website requests independently from the processing of async work items, allowing for more control over the scale out.

Comment: I don't see this becoming a high volume site any time in the foreseeable future. Mostly it's just a project for me to learn ASP.NET MVC on more then anything. I guess an alternative option would also be to just dump the files the user uploads into some folder that another program is monitoring right?

Comment: I agree with MSMQ, also consider Windows Azure Queues.

Comment: @Eric A: Yes, you could just dump each file into a folder individually.  Another process (e.g. a Windows Service) could pick up the files.  The Windows Service could principally live on another server at some point and access the file via network share.  If one does that at volume, you may need 2 NICs in your web servers... one to handle web traffic and one for the file copy / remote file access operations.